# Importing .png file runtime Unity Android

Tags: c#, android, image, unity-game-engine, import

I've got a problem during import a .png file to my project in code.
This is my .png file before importing:
[image]

After this code:

```
   var pngImage = LoadPNG(pngPath);
    string pngPath2 = Application.persistentDataPath + "/images/testImage.png";
    var meshRenderer = GameObject.Find("SimInput").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    meshRenderer.material.mainTexture = pngImage;


    public static Texture2D LoadPNG(string filePath)
{
    Texture2D tex = null;
    byte[] fileData;

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);            
        tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        tex.LoadImage(fileData); 
    }
    return tex;
}
```

I get the result as shown below:
[image]

Where am I doing a mistake?

I have been trying save this file again as a .png but the result was the same as on the first picture. Is there any property to change in Unity?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this the model you are trying to display the image a plane or quade? Are you using the default material and shader?

Comment: It's plane. I'm  using a default material and shader

Comment: seems the problem here is the underlying material. its black so your text isnt showing up, a good place to start would be to paint the background of the png white, so you can get rid of the alpha, alternatively try a whit under material

Comment: could be the shader too i suppose since it seems your light source is above the object, putting this side in shadow.

Comment: @Vanethrane - i've changed the position of lightsource but without effect. 
I guess that might be a problem with material. Can i set .png bg color in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a transparency issue. You are using the standard material which has it's *"Rendering Mode"* to set *"Opaque"*. You have to set that to *"Fade"* or *"Transparent"*. In this case *"Fade"*, should work better. After this, you can then control the *Metallic* and *Smoothness* sliders to make it darker or lighter. You can also use another shader such as *Sprites* ---> *Default*, *UI* ---> *Default* or *Unlit* ---> *Transparent* and they should work without having to set anything else.

[image]

---

While this will solve your issue, if all you need to do is display the loaded Texture, use the `RawImage` component. This is is the appropriate way to display `Texture2D`. To create it, go to *GameObject* ---> *UI* ---> *RawImage* then use the simple code below to display it on the *RawImage*.

```
//Set a RawImage in the Inspector
public RawImage rawImage;

void Start()
{
    Texture2D pngImage = LoadPNG(pngPath);
    rawImage.texture = pngImage;
}
```